# How can i input the data from kaggle into subplot individual bar graph?

Tags: keras, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, categorical-data, kaggle

[1]https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci/version/1

Im new to Python so excuse some technical words(doing AI Internship(Im Mech Engg))...im using the kaggle data to make a simple model to train...the method is categorical...with keras...now i want the same graphs in the kaggle data into my google colab via using sns or plt cmd or another easy to understand cmd...ive tried using "plt.imshow" but it doesnt work n shows error...Also i tried moving forward and do the work ahead but i cant train the model...and i dont know what to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRR0O.jpg

The first pic is my teacher's work...i want the kaggle graph's in that manner...in the subplots...
The 2nd and 3rd pic are my work...Ive imported the kaggle heart data and cleaned it...thats all what's not included in the pic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: np i found the solution...used histogram...thanks for the reply...